# Cocos2d: CCZ: Failed to uncompress data

Tags: android, google-play, cocos2d-x, texturepacker

I used expansion file(.obb) in my first coco2d-x3.0 android project, it worked fine in the local test( using adb push ...), but now when i download the .obb file from the google play, i have problem with loading assets(encrypted .pvr.ccz),and sometimes when i remove the app from the background apps and launch it again, it shows just black screen.

I have this message

```
cocos2d: CCZ: Failed to uncompress data
```

My texturepacker [configuration](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/uploads/default/7448/63c6b117297ce9dc.png).

My first customers complain, Please help me!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by using zip file and not the .obb file.